# How to Implement live video streaming in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, rtmp

I want to develop an e-learning app (website) using node.js in which the teacher can stream a live video by webcam and his students can see the live video lecture.

the idea of this live video streaming is similar to the zoom app.

The service I want is a one-to-many live stream such as I mentioned.

if there is a way to do this with WebSockets it will be better.

I found some things like Wowza, Webrtc, etc...

I want to find the best way of achieving such an app regarding the best solution as I haven't tried that kind of apps before.

For any details please, leave a comment.

Thanks,

Comment: Use Webrtc, it is p2p

Comment: I want one to many not p2p

Comment: is that helpful to stream for all clients?